# preg_replace image src

Tags: php, preg-replace, data-uri

I'm attempting to scan through my content and replace image source tags with something else (more notably, dataURIs when supported) - based on a couple of questions I've read through here, I'm trying `preg_replace()`:

```
// Base64 Encodes an image
function wpdu_base64_encode_image($imagefile) {
    $imgtype = array('jpg', 'gif', 'png');
    $filename = file_exists($imagefile) ? htmlentities($imagefile) : die($imagefile.'Image file name does not exist');
    $filetype = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if (in_array($filetype, $imgtype)){
        $imgbinary = fread(fopen($filename, "r"), filesize($filename));
    } else {
        die ('Invalid image type, jpg, gif, and png is only allowed');
    }
    return 'data:image/' . $filetype . ';base64,' . base64_encode($imgbinary);
}

// Do the do
add_filter('the_content','wpdu_image_replace');
function wpdu_image_replace($content) {
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    return preg_replace( '/<img.*src="(.*?)".*?>/', wpdu_base64_encode_image($upload_dir['path'].'/'.\1), $content );
}
```

The problem I'm running into is `wpdu_base64_encode_image($upload_dir['path'].'/'.\1)` which is basically outputting the `preg_replace` result - currently getting:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting T_STRING
```

`$upload_dir['path']` is correctly outputting the path to the image folder that I need, but there's also a few checks that I've tried and haven't been able to achieve as of yet:

1. Check if the image source is relative and if it is, strip off the domain (currently can be done with `site_url()` which I'm assuming would need to be of `preg_replace()`?)
2. If the image is not even local to the server (again - I'm assuming using the `site_url()` check), skip over it

I'm not as familiar with `preg_replace()` if anyone has suggestions, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

**Edit:** Should I use http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ instead? Seems like a pretty-heavy hammer, but if that's a more reliable way then I'm all for it - anyone use that before?

Answer (score 0):

In general, parsing HTML with regular expressions is not a very good idea and you should definitely look into using something else such as a proper HTML parser. You don't quite need simplehtmldom, the built-in `DOMDocument` and [`getElementsByTagName`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) will do the job nicely.

To get to your current problem, this type of transformation (where you want each replacement to be an *arbitrary function* of a match) is done using [`preg_replace_callback`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$path = $upload_dir['path']; // for brevity

return preg_replace_callback(
    '/<img.*src="(.*?)".*?>/',
    function ($matches) use($path) { 
        return wpdu_base64_encode_image($path.'/'.$matches[1]);
    },
    $content
);
```

Your current code attempts to use the placeholder `\1` in a completely unrelated context, which is why you get the parse error.